# Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $\int_{1}^{x^2} (\cos(\pi t))f(t)dt=\sqrt{x^2+x-2}$. Calculate $f(4)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

I would like to know if this is right. Thanks in advance for your time.

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $\int_{1}^{x^2} (\cos(\pi t)f(t)dt=\sqrt{x^2+x-2}$. Calculate $f(4)$.

$$\int_{1}^{x^2} (\cos(\pi t)f(t)dt=\sqrt{x^2+x-2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{x^2} (\cos(\pi t)f(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+x-2}$$
$$ \cos(\pi x^2)f(x^2)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x^2) =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+x-2}}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x^2+x-2)$$
$$ \cos(\pi x^2)f(x^2)\cdot 2x =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+x-2}}\cdot (2x+1)$$
$$ 2x\cos(\pi x^2)f(x^2)=\frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt{x^2+x-2}}$$
$$\frac{1}{2x\cos(\pi x^2)}\cdot 2x\cos(\pi x^2)f(x^2)=\frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt{x^2+x-2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2x\cos(\pi x^2)}$$
$$f(x^2)=\frac{2x+1}{4x\cos(\pi x^2)\sqrt{x^2+x-2}}$$
$$f(2^2)=\frac{2(2)+1}{4(2)\cos(\pi\cdot 2^2)\sqrt{2^2+2-2}}$$
$$f(4)=\frac{4+1}{8\cos(\pi\cdot 4)\sqrt{4+2-2}}$$
$$f(4)=\frac{5}{8\cos(4\pi)\sqrt{4}}$$
$$f(4)=\frac{5}{8\cdot 1 \cdot 2}$$
$$f(4)=\frac{5}{16}$$

Comment: Would have been simpler if you inputted $x = 2$ directly in the fifth step after doing the differentiation

Comment: @ayeayemaung thanks for answering.... understood.. but for the rest is the solution good?

Comment: Final answer is correct. As I said, I inputted $x = 2$ in the fifth step to verify the final answer.